# ES6 spread operator output

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a very basic question regarding spread operator. When we do

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(...numbers);
```

While it flattens out the list, is the output format actually a string like "1 2 3 4" OR are they still separate number list?

Comment: Spreading is equivalent to `console.log(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3])`, I'm not sure whether that answers your question, since I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: output format is not a string but 4 values in a row. It depends on your environment. Try, for example, `console.log({a:1},{b:2},3,4)` to see it's not a string. Alternatively try `console.log('1,2,3,4')` to see a string

Answer (score 1):

**Spread syntax** allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

In your example you would have

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(...numbers);

// This is the same
console.log(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Your values are spreaded as seperate values out of the array. You can do this with functions as well:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2];
const add = (a, b) => { return a + b; };
console.log(add(...numbers)); // -> add(1, 2) -> 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const [ firstNumber, ...restOfTheNumbers ] = numbers;
console.log(firstNumber, restOfTheNumbers);   // 1 [ 2, 3 ]
```